# how do i animate a div the width of each child image. and at the end return it to the beginning

Tags: jquery, carousel

I have written some code for a carousel but I think it needs a little work, firstly I will explain the DOM

container
images container
img
img
img
end images container
nav
left
right
end nav
end container

each img floats left but is a different width (Same height), I have used jQuery to get the width of the images container to be the same as the combined widths.

so this is my right click (haven't done left yet)

```
$('#container .container-nav .container-nav-right').click(function(){
    var scrollAmount = $('.container-images img').width();
    $("#container .container-images").animate({'left':'-=' + scrollAmount}, 'slow');
});
```

so this moves the container div along by say 230px each time, but I want it to move it 230, 240, 260 etc based on the images being contained.

I also want to reset the code once we get to the last image.

I know there are loads of plugin's out there but I want to try and understand this myself. I hope I'm explaining myself.

Anyone any ideas? or suggestions as to where I go from here? 
Thanks for reading this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little code to help explain kinakuta's answer:

```
var selectedImage = $('.container-images img:first');

$('#container .container-nav .container-nav-right').click(function(){
    var scrollAmount = selectedImage.width();
    $("#container .container-images").animate({'left':'-=' + scrollAmount}, 'slow');
    selectedImage = selectedImage.next();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to select each individual image - you're grabbing everything that matches your selector and it's only going to return the width() of the first one. One way to solve this is to add/remove a class for the "selected" image. You start with the first image having the "current" class, and use that to form a more specific selector. Then, when you move to the next image, remove it from the current one and add it to the next one.  There are other ways of accomplishing this, but off the top of my head, this would be my first strategy.

Oh, and I forgot the second part of your question. To get the next image, call the next() method on the current image. If nothing is returned, you've reached the end of your images and you can return to the beginning.